# How to fill arguments of method "withHeaders" from function

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Play Framework has method

```
def withHeaders(headers: (String, String)*): A
```

Now i use this method like this

```
BadRequest(renderErrorJson(ErrorType.BAD_REQUEST, message))
        .as(JSON)
        .withHeaders(("X-Api-Error-Guid", ErrorType.BAD_REQUEST.toString), ("X-Api-Error-Message", message))
```

I'd like to define and implement method, which could fill the args of "withHeaders" method

```
BadRequest(renderErrorJson(ErrorType.BAD_REQUEST, message))
        .as(JSON)
        .withHeaders(renderErrorHeaders(ErrorType.BAD_REQUEST, message))
```

Something like this, but it is not correct =)

```
  def renderErrorHeaders(error : ErrorType.Value, message : String): ((String,String)*) = {
    val firstHeader = ("X-Api-Error-Guid", error.toString)
    val secondHeader = ("X-Api-Error-Message", message)
    (firstHeader, secondHeader)
  }
```

Comment: WhoooHoooo! Thank you =)

Comment: If you find your question is a duplicate, please delete it: otherwise (up to five!) reviewers are spending time closing it out.